# Jenkins Git plugin, Error: Name must follow the pattern

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I receive an error after launching a Jenkins pipeline, but right at the SCM step, configure via the plugin (not by the groovy).

The message refers to a "Name" wrong spelled, but I can't figure out to which of my fields it is referring.

I looked to the source code, but it manipulates a concatenation of several inputs...

This is a git SCM.

[image: Jenkins interface]

> ERROR: Name must follow the pattern '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+((.|_|__|-+)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$' 
>  at hudson.util.FormValidation._errorWithMarkup(FormValidation.java:268) 
>  at hudson.util.FormValidation.errorWithMarkup(FormValidation.java:254) 
>  at hudson.util.FormValidation.error(FormValidation.java:145) 
>  at hudson.util.FormValidation.error(FormValidation.java:170) 
>  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.ImageNameValidator.validateName(ImageNameValidator.java:289) 
>  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.ImageNameValidator.validateUserAndRepo(ImageNameValidator.java:115) 
>  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.ImageNameValidator.checkUserAndRepo(ImageNameValidator.java:141) 
>  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.ImageNameValidator$checkUserAndRepo.call(Unknown Source) 
> + 50 lines I can show if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace contains org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.ImageNameValidator, so this error is for Docker image name validation, not your Git SCM.

Comment: Thanks, we have an image name generated from a Jenkins parameter. It seems that this feature is now disabled (security issue, I guess). So a `${abc}` is refused by the ImageNameValidator. It is painful that the error message doesn't display the string analysed.

Comment: I could think the problem was the consequence of a security patch not allowing me to inject a docker image name in a variable, but it's that the regex only accepts `'` and not `"`... I think this could be patched in Jenkins code.